# category/ url key not accept language other than english?

Tags: url, url-rewrite

i want to input some chinese url key for seo optimization in my region, but when i input some chinese character, the category and product was saved nothing.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not support unicode URL by default.

Problem 1

```
public function formatUrlKey($str)
{
    $urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', Mage::helper('catalog/product_url')->format($str));
    $urlKey = strtolower($urlKey);
    $urlKey = trim($urlKey, '-');

    return $urlKey;
}
```

Function **formatUrlKey** in class **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url** performs every time when you save your product. So it filters out everything from URL except digits and a-z characters.

Problem 2

You need to undecode your URL before searching it in database.

So you can write an extension yourself (check out [this](http://rakan.me/2012/07/19/support-unicode-in-magento-product-url-key/) blogpost) or you can buy one like [that](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/19389/).

Comment: the blogpost link is broken?

Comment: i found this module https://github.com/Minglong/Magento-unicode-URL

Comment: it does exactly what suggested in that blogpost