# Using chinese characters in base_url - how to edit regex in Http.php to allow valid() to pass?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, internationalization, multisite

for a multi-site setup we are about to launch a chinese store, which has chinese characters in the base url.
Howeverer, using .htaccess to load the correct store view, we receive a "Invalid URI supplied" error log and it also crashes the english view for that store, even though the english view doesn't have any chinese characters in the base_url.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

We are using 1.9.1 CE

Here is what I tried in the htaccess:

**EDIT:**

I've tried various modules, but all only seem to support url keys for products, categories and cms, but none seemt o address to the base_url issue.

I've tried this module: https://github.com/Minglong/Magento-unicode-URL

and I've also tried this: http://killerwhalesoft.com/blog/magento-unicode-url-key-products-categories-cms-pages/

Sorry, but some recent changes on StackExchange suddenly does not allow me to use chinese characters in the body `Body cannot contain -insert-chinese-symbol-`.

Please see this link for full code info ..

http://goo.gl/1aoSkF

Can anyone help identify the error with the above trace? Could the error come from the `_checkBaseUrl` function in `/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` ?

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, so I've tried to analyse the `lib/Zend/Uri/Http.php` file and I placed a log output in the valid() function to see which throws the error. According to the log 
The error seems to come from the `validatePath()` function.

When logging with this function I receive the following:

```
2015-08-17T08:52:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): path : /-chinese-chars-here-/shop/
2015-08-17T08:52:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): pattern : /^(?:\/(?:(?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\]:@&=+$,;])*)?)+$/
2015-08-17T08:52:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): status : 0
```

So I need to edit the regex values so it allows chinese vars - specifically this part of the __construct() function in Http.php:

```
const CHAR_ALNUM    = 'A-Za-z0-9';
const CHAR_MARK     = '-_.!~*\'()\[\]';
const CHAR_RESERVED = ';\/?:@&=+$,';
const CHAR_SEGMENT  = ':@&=+$,;';
const CHAR_UNWISE   = '{}|\\\\^`';
```

To make this validation work:

```
        // Escaped special characters (eg. '%25' for '%')
    $this->_regex['escaped']    = '%[[:xdigit:]]{2}';

    // Unreserved characters
    $this->_regex['unreserved'] = '[' . self::CHAR_ALNUM . self::CHAR_MARK . ']';

    // Segment can use escaped, unreserved or a set of additional chars
    $this->_regex['segment']    = '(?:' . $this->_regex['escaped'] . '|[' .
        self::CHAR_ALNUM . self::CHAR_MARK . self::CHAR_SEGMENT . '])*';

    // Path can be a series of segmets char strings seperated by '/'
    $this->_regex['path']       = '(?:\/(?:' . $this->_regex['segment'] . ')?)+';

    // URI characters can be escaped, alphanumeric, mark or reserved chars
    $this->_regex['uric']       = '(?:' . $this->_regex['escaped'] . '|[' .
        self::CHAR_ALNUM . self::CHAR_MARK . self::CHAR_RESERVED .

    // If unwise chars are allowed, add them to the URI chars class
        (self::$_config['allow_unwise'] ? self::CHAR_UNWISE : '') . '])';
```

Comment: can you post the relevant information from your .htaccess

Comment: I've edited the info into the question.

Comment: okay check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49187/category-url-key-not-accept-language-other-than-english

Comment: Thanks. I saw this previously, but since no product or categories have special character paths I didn't think this applied to the base_url.

Comment: I think Magento as a whole doesn't support these types of characters (without modification), someone might chime in with a work around.

Comment: Thanks all, I've made some edits and added the error trace here: http://goo.gl/1aoSkF - Can anyone help identify the error and a possible fix?

Answer (score 4):

So I've lookup how to the support for Unicode characters in the given Zend Library.

From the PHP docs: [Unicode character properties](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) and [Pattern modifiers](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

In `Zend/Uri/Http.php` you'll need to edit two properties.

1. `const CHAR_ALNUM    = '\p{Han}A-Za-z0-9';` Change to add support for Unicode Han
2. Add a pattern modifier `/u` in `validatePath()`
   public function validatePath($path = null)
   {
       if ($path === null) {
           $path = $this->_path;
       }

   ```
   // If the path is empty, then it is considered valid
   if (strlen($path) === 0) {
       return true;
   }

   // Determine whether the path is well-formed
   $pattern = '/^' . $this->_regex['path'] . '$/u';
   $status  = @preg_match($pattern, $path);
   if ($status === false) {
       #require_once 'Zend/Uri/Exception.php';
       throw new Zend_Uri_Exception('Internal error: path validation failed');
   }

   return (boolean) $status;
   ```

   }

I focused on the path section, but the same will go for other sections.

**Also, copy the modified file to app/code/local/Zend/Uri/Http.php, this will override the original file and won't be overwritten with a Magento update**

Comment: Also, copy the modified file to `app/code/local/Zend/Uri/Http.php`, this will override the original file and won't be overwritten with a Magento update